# Prism: How to render one view on top of another

Tags: wpf, rendering, prism

We have a Prism/WPF application and are using an expander to animate a menu.

When the expander expands, the content is rendered behind the main region's content.

The menu is in a different region than the content it is supposed to overlay (since the menu governs what items go into that region) which is why this is occurring.  We have tried setting the Z-Index of the ContentControls to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried swapping the order of the `ContentControl`?

Place your `MainContent` region `ContentControl` in the grid first, then your `DropdownRegion` `ContentControl` secondly.

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentControl" />
    <ContentControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="DropdownRegion" />
</Grid>
```

This is because in XAML, Control placement order dictates rendering order

Answer (score 0):

If you put two things in the same Grid cell, they overlay.  Here's an example where I overlay two images in a grid, but don't specify a cell (meaning column 0, row 0):

```
<Grid>
     <Image Source="blah.jpg" />
     <Image Source="another.jpg" />
</Grid>
```

Generally you will want to look more toward layout panels for things like this, rather than traditional Z-Order type of strategies.

Comment: This is not the issue. We something like this (skipping unnecessary code like column/row defs): <Grid> <contentcontrol regionname = "dropdownregion"> <contentcontrol regionname = "maincontent"> </Grid> Then using prism, we add a dropdown view in the dropdown region and content view in the main content. When the dropdown drops down, it's items are rendered behind the main content.